# How to programmatically define a rule in clipspy?

Tags: python, clips, clipspy

Just installed [clipspy](https://pypi.org/project/clipspy/) on Fedora 26. I can assert simple facts like so:

```
>>> from clips import Environment
>>> env = Environment()
>>> env.assert_string('(a)')
ImpliedFact: f-1     (a)
```

How do I programmatically define a rule please? I can't find any examples or documentation about that. TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the documentation here: [clipspy documentation](https://clipspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clips.html)

However, you can either use build or eval like in CLIPS:

```
>>> env.build(...your defrule)
>>> env.eval("(build ...)")
```

or you can create it with:

```
clips.agenda.Rule(env, rule_you_want_to_define)
```

Don't forget the " " around your rule definition.

Comment: Thank you. The following works
    env.build("(defrule r1 (a) => (assert (b)))")
so I have accepted the answer. However. Giving the same input to env.eval gives
    [EXPRNPSR3] Missing function declaration for defrule.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/clips/environment.py", line 168, in eval
    raise CLIPSError(self._env)
clips.error.CLIPSError: [EXPRNPSR3] Missing function declaration for defrule.

Comment: Giving the same input directly to `Rule` (e.g., `Rule(env, ...)`) and then trying to print the rule gives `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/clips/agenda.py", line 223, in __repr__
    string = lib.EnvGetDefrulePPForm(self._env, self._rule)
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'void *' must be a cdata pointer, not Environment`

Comment: I edited my answer. The problem in eval is, that you have to evaluate a build function. Otherwise CLIPS will interpret defrule as function an therefore you get [EXPRNPSR3] Missing function declaration for defrule. Your other problem is python related. Without your code I can't say nothing.

Comment: Author here, do not use class constructors to build rules or facts. Those objects are returned by the `Environment` methods. To define rules/deftemplates/declasses/etc you need to pass `CLIPS` code to the `Environment.build` method. Another way is to write your definitions in a file and use the `Environment.load` method as for the example in the README.